# For spinnaker pipeline, how set variables from a yaml resource in s3 bucket?

Tags: spinnaker

I would like to use a yaml file that is stored in s3 to update variable values to be used in pipeline expressions.

I checked and found helper function #yamlFromUrl(String). I read the documentation and found it uses #fromUrl(String) underneath and You can use this to fetch information from unauthenticated URL endpoints.
I am not sure if it is the right way to read yaml file from s3. How should I proceed?